# 'Doing for someone' -- correct expression for cleaning or housekeeping?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, british-english

Looking for a likely expression a maid in 1930s England would use to say she's cleaning or keeping house for someone. Is 'I'm used to doing for an older gentleman' or 'He's clearly used to doing for himself' the right expression?

Comment: I have heard the expression often in the UK but not for some time. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doing+for+him%2C+doing+for+himself.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoing%20for%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoing%20for%20himself%20.%3B%2Cc0) shows it was common at the turn of the century and does not seem to favour AmE or BrE, surprisingly.

Comment: I have not had much success in researching this, probably because of the simplicity of 'do for' and the difficulty of tracking such quotes. We may have to rely on anecdotal evidence.

Comment: I can certainly remember it being used, both in life (from about 1959) and in films dealing with the era.

Comment: For what it's worth, the OED records this usage as follows:  'b. colloq. To attend to; esp. to perform household tasks for, esp. as an employee.' It gives the following examples of usage: 
1844   J. T. J. Hewlett Parsons & Widows III. xliii. 123   *The slip-shod maid who did for the lodgers.*
1878   I. L. Bird Lady's Life Rocky Mts. (1879) ix. 156   *The men don't like ‘baching’, as it is called in the wilds—i.e. ‘doing for themselves’.*
1914   B. Stoker Judge's House in Dracula's Guest 21   *He..got..the name of an old woman who would probably undertake to ‘do’ for him.*

Comment: 1936   A. Christie Cards on Table xiv. 136   *The superintendent's researches..led him..to Mrs. Astwell—who ‘did’ for the ladies at Wendon Cottage.*
1997   Daily Tel. 3 Apr. 34/6   *Mrs Simmons has ‘done for’ Mrs Lynton-Smith for 24 years.*

Comment: Note that in many instances the *do* is in scare quotes, including in the Agatha Christie text. Thus it was considered quite colloquial (as opposed to part of Standard English) even at the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's incredibly helpful and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression was so ingrained in British colloquial speech in the 1930s and 40s that "Can I do you now sir?" was a catch phrase for the char lady character Mrs Mopp in the BBC radio comedy [ITMA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_That_Man_Again) which ran from 1939 to 1949. However no one uses it now. If it was used now it would probably be interpreted sexually.

Comment: Oh how funny! 

Comment: That's why it had sounded strange to me when I wanted to use it now but I could have sworn it was 'innocent' back then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this expression. My great-grandmother used to ‘do-for’ Emily Pankhurst so I hope this knowledge is ‘in my genes’!

It sounds odd saying ‘I’m used to ‘doing for’ an older gentleman’ I mean, the ‘used to’ sounds odd. You want to say ‘I’m doing it regularly’? In which case I’d just say ‘I’m ‘doing for’ an elderly gentleman.’ Which already carries the sense of ‘regularly’ because ‘doing’ is continuous.

The ‘doing for’ sounds fine but I think you should put it in quotes as commenters have suggested.

I remember people saying ‘doing for’ in quotes ie with a tiny pause before, denoting that.

I have heard Mrs. Bridges (the housekeeper) say it to the chamber maid, in ‘Upstairs-Downstairs’ a popular long-running serial about ‘life below-stairs’ ie in the servant quarters of a grand home. This could be rich source material for you, if you don’t already know it!

Upstairs Downstairs
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tXuW9u-CAgs

‘He’s clearly used to ‘doing for’ himself’ seems fine, again, I would put the ‘doing for’ in quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I love Upstairs-Downstairs -- a treasure trove indeed!

Comment: yes it’s a classic isn’t it?!